# Should I use 'dump pocket' or 'dumping pocket' in this situation?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

You have a small toy dump truck filled with some stuff, and you are about to dump it out into your pocket. Now you want to call this pocket with extra adjective dump. Should it be "a dump pocket" or "a dumping pocket"?

Comment: Did you find *dump(ing) pocket* used anywhere?

Comment: Grammatically, both are fine.

Comment: @AlanCarmack, thanks. But how about meaningwise? Grammar is not the one I want to understand the sentences with.

Answer (score 2):

> To dump

can mean to put things into an area without care.

If you have a pocket that you constantly put things into, you might call it a

> dumping pocket

in the same way that

> dumping ground

is used to describe a junk yard or tipping field.

Answer (score 1):

By "a dump pocket" are you referring to the fact the pocket is used for dumping things in? Or are you referring to the fact that something has currently been dumped into it?

For the first scenario, the word "pocket" already implies that its use is storage related, so you don't need an adjective to go with it.

For the second scenario, you would call the pocket "full".